# Exchanging pieces when up...not this time!

Tags: endgame, trading, exchange

```
[FEN "8/ppk3pr/2n5/8/8/P7/1P1RK1R1/8 w - - 1 1"] 

1. Kf3 Nd8 2. Rg6 Nf7 3. Kf4 Rh4+ 4. Kg3 Rh7 5. Rd5 a6 6. Rf5 Nd6 7. Rc5+ Kb6 8. Rd5 1-0
```

Played recently. I concluded that simply ganging up on the g7 pawn would risk that Black might just jettison it and K and N will run into my queenside before I can defend it properly, whereas with both rooks on the board I can quickly pester Black on both wings, maybe combined with a few mate hints. I.e., counterexample to "trade pieces when up". In the actual game I squeezed him with the defense of the g7 pawn first, then he promptly hung his knight into a pin vindicating me, but Black was 300 Elo lower than me.

**What do the engines say about this position?**

(Yes, I can simply feed it into LiChess, but since Black has so many moves, I have too much "forward split".)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I assume the question is something like "Was I correct to not exchange rooks" but we all know what happens when you assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted this into [lichess](https://lichess.org/analysis/8/ppk3pr/2n5/8/8/P7/1P1RK1R1/8_w_-_-_0_1?color=white#0), and just following the engine's (SF16) main line for 5 moves with depth > 30 and three variations, I got this:

```
[FEN "8/ppk3pr/2n5/8/8/P7/1P1RK1R1/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Kd1 a6 2. Kc2 g6 3. Rxg6 Ne5 4. Rg3 Rf7 5. Rdg2 Nc6 6. Rg7
```

Black is lost, and the engine doesn't seem to care about the pawn and offers it quite quickly. However, the engine wants to trade rooks as White in this position and avoid that as Black.
All best moves for Black according to the engine prevent the rook trade. Against almost all other moves, the engine wants to trade the rooks with White (e.g. after 5 ..Nc6).

So even in this position, it seems to be a good idea to trade material when up. However, as Black is lost anyways, it was certainly OK to decide against trading rooks and win in another fashion.

Comment: Makes sense - engines know no fear :-)